# Issue on Pentaho "org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed."

Tags: excel, pentaho

I've a little problem with pentaho.

The thing is that I've a mistake in "Executions Results" here logging...

`2015/03/04 12:41:16 - Spoon - Transformation opened.
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - Spoon - Launching transformation [plazo_x_cliente4]...
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - Spoon - Started the transformation execution.
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente4 - Dispatching started for transformation [plazo_x_cliente4]
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - Transformation metadata - Natural sort of steps executed in 0 ms (3 time previous steps calculated)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.0 - Finished reading query, closing connection.
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.0 - Finished processing (I=1, O=0, R=0, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - Copy rows to result 2.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) : Unexpected error
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) : org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed.
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) : File closed.
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) : 
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) :     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelwriter.ExcelWriterStep.closeOutputFile(ExcelWriterStep.java:221)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) :     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelwriter.ExcelWriterStep.processRow(ExcelWriterStep.java:168)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) :     at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:40)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) :     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) : Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed.
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) :     at org.apache.commons.vfs.util.MonitorOutputStream.assertOpen(Unknown Source)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) :     at org.apache.commons.vfs.util.MonitorOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) :     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(Unknown Source)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) :     at java.io.FilterOutputStream.close(Unknown Source)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) :     at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelwriter.ExcelWriterStep.closeOutputFile(ExcelWriterStep.java:219)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) :     ... 3 more
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente.xlsx.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=2, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=1)
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - Spoon - The transformation has finished!!
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente4 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente4 - ERROR (version 4.2.1-stable, build 15952 from 2011-10-25 15.27.10 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente4 - plazo_x_cliente4
2015/03/04 12:41:16 - plazo_x_cliente4 - plazo_x_cliente4`

Basically I've been trying to exporting of "Input table" to "Microsoft Excel Writer"
In addition
I have Windows 7,
Pentaho 4.2.1-stable
And Excel 2007 (extension xlsx)

There is, however, something strange in all of this. Nevertheless the information is updated on the excel file, that is good but the second transformation after of this don't run.

Hearty thanks to you

---

Thanks Rishu for your answer...

I've been trying to run the transformation without the job and the issue this on transformation. I guess.

Can you help me?

I'm using "Microsoft Excel Writer", Must I use "Microsoft Excel Output"? I tell you because I've read your blog.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Two Possible issues with the log provided:

1. It seems that the parameters are not passing correctly into your next transformations. You are using "Copy rows to result" step *(from the log)*. Check whether the parameters are properly defined. I assume your next transformation is not able to read the parameters. You can also read [this](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/using-copy-rows-to-result-in-pentaho-data-integration/).
2. If point #1 is correct, try checking if only the second transformation is getting executing properly without actually executing the entire job. You manually entry of the parameters, just for a test purpose. I assume there might be some issue with the source of the 2nd transformation.

Please check. Hope it helps :)

---

**Adding more details**

The issue is not with the use of any particular step. Using either microsoft excel output or excel writer will work the same. What you need to understand is the use of "copy rows to result". Just read my blog above or [pentaho wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/Copy+rows+to+result). It might be of some help.

What you should do (in short)::
Take 2 transformation > table input and copy rows in the first ktr > in the second ktr use excel writer with the variables defined. [*note: you need to do some changes in the ktr settings; which i have explained in the blog*]

Comment: Thanks Rishu for your answer...

I've been trying to run the transformation without the job and the issue this on transformation. I guess.

Can you help me?

I'm using "Microsoft Excel Writer", Must I use "Microsoft Excel Output"? I tell you because I've read your blog.

Thanks again

Comment: Input Table > Copy rows to result > Microsoft Excel Writer

Comment: Wow, thanks for your help, Already allowed me to run all trasformation pretty good, but I have some issues yet.

Comment: Copy rows to result.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=0, R=1, W=1, U=0, E=0). Unexpected error. org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed. at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelwriter.ExcelWriterStep.closeOutputFile(ExcelWriterStep.java:221). at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelwriter.ExcelWriterStep.processRow(ExcelWriterStep.java:168) at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:40).  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: org.apache.commons.vfs.FileSystemException: File closed. at org.apache.commons.vfs.util...